# Use Excel if statement based on the VALUE OF THE CALCULATION of another cell instead of the contents of that cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

I was wondering if there was an easy way to pass the value of a calculation to another function, for instance the if statement.

[A1] = 10

[B1] =IF(A1<0,1,"")

Result:

Value of [B1] is a blank  (correct). Since Cell A is greater than 0, it returns a blank.

Now we try

[C1] = IF(B1>0,1,50)

Value of [C1] incorrectly says 1

Since cell B1 is blank, i would expect it to return 50. But it doesn't it returns 1.

I think this has to do with how excel is valuing a blank result from a formula differently then valuing a normal blank cell.

Now we try:

[A2] = 10

[B2] = (leave blank)

[c2] = If(b2>0,20,50)

the the result in [C2] is 50.

To take it a step further with the same example.

[A3] = 10

[B3] = (leave blank)

[C3] = A3*B3

The value in C3 will be 0. (correct, anything times 0 is 0)

But if we make:

[A4] = 10

[B4] = If(A4<10,1,"")

[C4] = A4*B4

The value in [C4] "#VALUE!"

The calculation in C4 is trying to solve for a "Blank" formula differently than if the value of that cell was truly "Blank"

So my question is, how do we write [C1 or C4] so that it interprets the same way as [C2 or C3].

****If i replace the value of [B4] (pressing f2 then f9) then [C4] works like [C3], but i don't want to do that and I am trying to avoid making macros.

Comment: It doesn't matter if A3 contains value `-90` or formula `=a1+a2`. In both cases formula `=IF(A3<0,50,"")` should give exactly the same result.

Comment: I tested your code and couldn't reproduce your issue. The code worked as expected (after the `else` syntax error was removed).

Comment: Sorry, bouncing back and forth between programming languages recently and blended a couple. I removed the 'else' in my post. I have tried to simplify this example dramatically from what i normally do and perhaps something has been lost in translation. I will come back with a more concrete example. I concur the dropping the 'else' makes it work and perhaps in my more complex calculations I have something else going on. However, I know that I have had more complex formulas that interpret that the cell is filled with a formula and the '<0' doesn't give me a 'false' return on the if statement.

Comment: Updated the question to more accurately reflect what I am trying to get answered.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your if expression. Try :

```
=IF(A3<0,50,"")
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

I see now that a blank cell is not the same as an function that results in an empty string. It looks like there is a clever way to handle this via the "Count blank" function and if necessary a "nested if" in the 'false' portion of the first if that is returning the true value for your blank result.

```
[C1] = if(countblank(b1),50,1)
```

This will make C1 return 50 if b1 is blank or return 1 if it is not blank.
For the second example, where i actually have a calculation going on:

```
[C4] = if(countblank(A4:B4),0,A4*B4)
```

This means that if there are any blanks between A4 and C4 then it will return the product that I know we would be receiving if the value was B4 was actually blank.

I usually create a lot of spreadsheets where I like to hide values/formulas if their result does not need to be shown but I still need to do a calculation in case the formula spills into extra rows. For example:

```
 =IF(COUNTBLANK(A11),"",IF(J10+H11-I11>0,J10+H11-I11,""))
```

This would hide the result (blank it out) if the 'key column' is blank. But if the 'key column' is not blank, it will perform the calculation and if the result of that calculation was not valid, then it will hide that cell as well.

Comment: A common method to test for a blank is like this - =IF(A1="","",50) which will return a blank if A1 is blank, either truly blank or filed with a "null string" returned by a formula. Another possibility is to test the length, =IF(LEN(A1)=0,.....

Answer (score 0):

An empty string ("") is not the same as an empty cell, as you have discovered.

There is no way in Excel for a formula or a UDF to return an empty cell: you can return either "" or zero: so you need to write your formulas to handle that or to convert from "" to zero.